# graphql / Apollo test case fails Error: Expected one matching operation for criteria "Match DocumentNode", found none

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine, apollo

I am trying to write a test for an angular service which I am using with graphql & Apollo.

I'm receiving these errors: `Error: Expected one matching operation for criteria "Match DocumentNode", found none.`

and
`Error: Expected no open operations, found 1:`

**foo.spec.ts**

```
    import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import {
```

....

```
const fragment: DocumentNode = gql`
  fragment SummaryDetails on SummaryDetails {
    foo
```

...
}
`;

```
const summaryQuery: DocumentNode = gql`
  query Summary(

  ) {
    Summary(

    ) {
      ...SummaryDetails
    }
  }
  ${fragment}
`;

const fundDataServiceParams: FundDataServiceParams = {
  foo ...
};

const expectedRawSummaryDetails: any = {
  Summary: [
    {
      foo ...
    },
  ],
};

const expectedSummaryDetails: SummaryDetail[] = [
  {
    foo ...
  },
];

describe('FundSummaryServiceRegisterMethod', () => {
  let controller: ApolloTestingController;
  let fundSummaryService: FundSummaryService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ApolloTestingModule, HttpClientTestingModule],

    });

    controller = TestBed.inject(ApolloTestingController);
    foo = TestBed.inject(foo);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    controller.verify();
  });

  fit('should return foodetails', (done: DoneFn) => {
    fundSummaryService
      .register(fragment, fundDataServiceParams)
      .subscribe((foo) => {
        expect(foo).toEqual(foo);
        done();
      });

    const op = controller.expectOne(fooQuery);
    expect(op.operation.variables.foo).toEqual(foo.foo); 
    op.flushData(expectedfoo);
  });

});
```

Note: I tried this [old post's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54449365/failed-expected-one-matching-operation-for-criteria-match-documentnode-found), didn't work.

Comment: Did you solve this issue

Comment: no I wasn't able to

Answer (score 1):

The good news for you is that in the `afterEach`, `controller.verify()` is failing meaning there is a query in queue and not all of them have been dealt with. I am thinking that your `summaryQuery` is slightly off where it is not matching exactly the query where the `afterEach` is saying is still in queue and has not been flushed.

I think you can use a different definition of `expectOne` from the [documentation](https://apollo-angular.com/docs/development-and-testing/testing) to match the query in queue. I don't have much experience with Apollo or GraphQL but try something like this for the `expectOne`:

```
const op = controller.expectOne(operation => {
  // can assert some stuff on the operation like the documentation shows
  return true;
});
```

If the above works, it most likely means that `summaryQuery` does not match the query that `ApolloTestingController` sees.